# Custom Authentication in laravel 5.5 Not logging in?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5, laravel-authorization

I am learning laravel and i decided to make a custom authentication in laravel . I could register my users but when i try to login i get this error ?

```
Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given,
```

These are my resources
My AdminUser Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticableTrait;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
class AdminUser extends Eloquent implements AuthenticatableContract,AuthorizableContract
{
    public $table = "admin_users";
    use Notifiable;
    use AuthenticableTrait;
    use Authorizable;
    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

My AdminUserController

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\AdminUser;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use App\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\RegisterRequest;
use Auth;
use Response;

class AdminUserController extends Controller {

    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    /**
     * the model instance
     * @var AdminUser
     */
    protected $user;
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Authenticator
     */
    protected $admin;

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @param  Authenticator  $admin
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $admin, AdminUser $user)
    {
        $user = AdminUser::first();
        Auth::login($user);

        $this->middleware('admin', ['except' => ['getLogout']]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the application registration form.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getRegister()
    {
        return view('admin/admin_users/register');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a registration request for the application.
     *
     * @param  RegisterRequest  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postRegister(RegisterRequest $request)
    {
        AdminUser::create([
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => bcrypt($request->password),
        ]);
        return redirect('backend-admin/dashboard');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application login form.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getLogin()
    {
        return view('admin/admin_users/login');
    }

    /**
     * Handle a login request to the application.
     *
     * @param  LoginRequest  $request
     * @return Response
     */
    public function postLogin(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        if (Auth::guard('admin')->attempt($request->only('email', 'password')))
        {
            return redirect()->intended('/backend-admin/dashboard');
        }

        return redirect('/backend-admin')->withErrors([
            'email' => 'The credentials you entered did not match our records. Try again?',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out of the application.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function getLogout()
    {
        Auth::guard('admin')->logout();

        return redirect('/backend-admin');
    }
    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }

}
```

My VerifyAdmin Middleware

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class VerifyAdmin
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $admin;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
//        dd($auth);
        $this->admin = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if ($this->admin->guest())
        {
            if ($request->ajax())
            {
                return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            }
            else
            {
                return redirect()->guest('backend-admin');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

}
```

I also defined guards in auth.php

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\AdminUser::class,
        ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Also defined middleware in kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
    'admin' => \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyAdmin::class,
```

Feel free to correct me if i am wrong anywhere or if i have missed anything .

Comment: You're not posting the part or file that has SessionGuard. That will show you what your are missing. None of these files have what the error is pointing too.

Comment: so how am i supposed to do that ?

Comment: Can you find where SessionGuard is called from? You will find the answer there.

Comment: I get this typical error
Type error: Argument 2 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider, null given, called in D:\My Web Work\whitefeathers\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php on line 125

Comment: `public function createSessionDriver($name, $config)
    {
        $provider = $this->createUserProvider($config['provider'] ?? null);
        $guard = new SessionGuard($name, $provider, $this->app['session.store']); `

Looks like your problem is that '$provider' is coming up null in your config. 

[link](https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/master/AuthManager.php) line:121

Take a look at **createSessionDriver($name, $config)** in **UserProvider.php**. What ever is set for $config or not configured correctly there is your culprit.

Comment: I found what was bugging my program , i did defined guard function in my controller but forget to add the guard in function , i fixed it by defining guard.

Comment: Please add that as your answer and accept that if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I found what was bugging my program , i did defined guard function in my controller but forget to add the guard in function , i fixed it by defining guard.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem are those 2 lines:

```
$user = AdminUser::first();
Auth::login($user);
```

What's the point of running it? First of all, I see you have here login action and it seems you automatically login admin when on login page - it doesn't make much sense.

Also those 2 lines won't do anything that should be done I think - because when admin logs in, well you log him in so there's no point to login him in each request assuming you are using sessions.

Comment: when i remove those lines i get this error 
Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.
    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies

Comment: @designerdarpan So you should probably exclude also `getLogin` and `postLogin` actions: `$this->middleware('admin', ['except' => ['getLogout', 'getLogin', 'postLogin']]);`

Comment: when i do that i get redirect back to login page

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the admin provider name from `admin` to `admins`.

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],
    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
    ],
    'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],
        'admins' => [  // ***this is the change that should be made***
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\AdminUser::class,
        ],
    ],
    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```